# How can I install tensorflow on mac using pip?

Tags: macos, tensorflow, pip, protocol-buffers

I have been getting the same error in the picture below for the following commands: `pip3 install tensorflow` or `pip3 install protobuf`. How can I solve this problem? Thanks. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a virtual environment. Works most efficiently.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3 myTestEnv
source myTestEnv/bin/activate
pip3 install --upgrade pip3
pip3 install tensorflow
```